# linq query read only

Tags: vb.net, linq, readonly

I am completely stumped on this issue. I have been searching for a while now and still have no answer for how to solve the problem.

I run a query in which I attempt to set the value on. The problem is that they come up as `read only` variables if I do not specify `Select New With`. When I specify `Select New With` it doesn't update the database. Some of the code is listed below.

My goal is to allow the shooter to update the `DataGridView` which would update the database. I was told in another question on StackOverflow that the `DataGridView` would not update the database simply by the user inputting data. So I created a update button which runs the code listed below.

Code:

Query using `Select New With` allows me to edit variables but won't commit to database:

```
Dim query = From t In db.Trophies _
            Select New With {t.TrophyName, t.WinnerId, t.Name, t.Score, t.Printed}
```

Query won't let me edit variables. Error message reads "Property 'TrophyName' is 'ReadOnly':

```
Dim query = From t In db.Trophies _
            Select t.TrophyName, t.WinnerId, t.Name, t.Score, t.Printed
```

Code where I want to update the results:

```
Dim i as integer = 0
For Each result In query
    result.WinnerId = dgvTrophies.Rows(i).Cells(dgvTrophies.Columns("WinnerId").Index).Value
    result.Name = dgvTrophies.Rows(i).Cells(dgvTrophies.Columns("Name").Index).Value
    result.Score = dgvTrophies.Rows(i).Cells(dgvTrophies.Columns("Score").Index).Value
    db.SubmitChanges()
    i += 1
Next
```

Table:

```
PRIMARY KEY TrophyId int auto-increments
TrophyName varchar(50)
WinnerId char(7) Allow Nulls
Name varchar(20) Allow Nulls
Score int Allow Nulls
Printed bit
```

Any advice or answers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried setting `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to `True` but it didn't solve the issue.

EDIT: To get it to do a more "automatic" update, after the user leaves `edit mode` on the `DataGridView` I call `db.SubmitChanges` which updates the database and no longer requires an update button.

Comment: You should show your first query, the one you posted won't work since you are using a new anonymous type...

Comment: Does your `Tropies` table declare a PK?  You won't be able to make changes without one.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, I have updated my post with the `Trophies table`

Comment: Needing to call `dgvTrophies.Rows(i).Cells(...)` is odd to me. Normally with data binding you don't reference cells of DataGridView. What are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Neolisk I went ahead and updated the main post with my goal. I would like to allow the user to enter information into the `DataGridView` and have that information be updated into the table, either automatically or manually.

Comment: @MichaelStramel: DataGridView would not update the database, but your underlying object/data layer will. You can [DataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx(v=vs.80).aspx) to send changes back to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Select new with { ...` creates an anonymous object, and changes to that is not submited to the database. You need to work with the linq entities. For Example:

```
Dim query = From t In db.Trophies _
            Select t
```

Or simply

```
Dim query = db.Trophies
```

That will work.

Comment: So I can't select in the query what columns I would like to update in the query?

Comment: No, you need to select the complete entity.

Comment: That allowed my manual update to work. Is there anyway to make these changes automatic when the user edits the information?

Comment: Also you should move the `db.SubmitChanges()` to after the loop for better performance.

Comment: I originally had the `db.SubmitChanges()` after the loop. I was moved it around thinking it might possibly have a problem with it.